# how to use easypermissions library in google maps in android?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, permissions, permission-denied

I need to show my location, it work nicely in some device but in some version of android map doesn't working , application was crashing.
Please some one can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Gradle

compile 'lalosoft.android-utilities:easypermissions:1.0.1'

After that extends EasyPermissionActivity
and then override

@Override

```
public void onRequestPermissionGranted(String[] permission, int[] grantResults) {
    // The permissions were granted
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionDenied(String[] permission, int[] grantResults) {
    // The permissions were denied
}
```